# FIREBASE ANALYTICS. Get analysis report then render to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm currently using Firebase JS SDK at Client and ExpressJS + Cloud Functions at Server. Is there any way to get All Users from my apps and then render it to HTML (Client).
[image: My Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). The Measurement Protocol API allows you to make HTTP requests to send events directly to Google Analytics servers. This allows developers to measure how users interact with their business from any HTTP-enabled environment. Notably, this makes it easy to measure interactions that happen server-to-server.